# Identify duplicate value in array of objects with a type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some typescript mapping arrays in my Angular app. See example below.

Is there is a way to have an error (build / type) when someone adds an object which has a `path` that already exists?

I've seen examples with flat arrays, but not with a specific property (`path`) in an array of objects.

I would also add that in my specific case (slightly different from my example) I don't want to merge the objects.

If needed I could create the mappings via a function as long as the error is not runtime.

```js
interface MappedPath {
   path: string; // I always want this to be unique.
   personal: { name?: string; email?: string; } // ignore this can be same or different.
}

// should error as duplicate path values used.
const array: MappedPath[] = [
   {
     path: '/same/path/here',
     personal: { name: 'Henry' }
   },
   {
     path: '/same/path/here',
     personal: { email: 'x@gmail.com' }
   }
]

// no errors. unique 'path' but 'personal' is same.
const array: MappedPath[] = [
   {
     path: '/path/A',
     personal: { email: 'x@gmail.com' }
   },
   {
     path: '/path/A/somewhere',
     personal: { email: 'x@gmail.com' }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified duplicate remover function like so :

```js
const invalid = [
  { path: 'some/path', data: {} },
  { path: 'some/path', data: {} },
];

const valid = [
  { path: 'some/different/path', data: {} },
  { path: 'some/path', data: {} },
];


checkUnicity(valid);
checkUnicity(invalid);

function checkUnicity(items) {
  if (
    items.some((v, i, a) => a
      .indexOf(
        items.find((item) => item.path === v.path)) !== i
      )
  ) throw new Error('Duplicated path');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no stand-alone `type` which can represent such relations in TypeScript. Instead, we can use a generic helper function to initialize the array.

```
type ValidateMappedPath<
  T extends MappedPath[], 
  P extends string = never,
  O = T
> = T extends [infer L extends MappedPath, ...infer R extends MappedPath[]]
      ? L["path"] extends P
        ? never
        : ValidateMappedPath<R, P | L["path"], O>
      : O

function createMappedPath<
  T extends (MappedPath & { path: P })[], 
//                          ^^^^^^^ this makes sure that path is narrowed to 
//                                  be a string literal type                  
  P extends string
>(mappedPath: ValidateMappedPath<[...T]>){
//                               ^^^^^^ infer T to be a tuple and not an array
    return mappedPath
}
```

The generic function takes the array as the parameter and infers its type into `T`. The recursive `ValidateMappedPath` iterates through the array and checks for duplicate `path` values. If it finds any, the `mappedPath` parameter is typed as `never` leading to a compile time error.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4YgEwApxgAWyA3gFDJUaFEBcyAzmFKAOYDcyA9N8gJLI4AGwDucAJ6Nk48MmLBpYAPbIARigCuIYAEdNEAHSVq0RspAiGpZJYC2EAPwNmrEJ2QQ7cYMOdMWdi4AXx4%20YDYQZSgUBWkEOBB1FEY4B2Ro5BxgGBhoCHBjYPJyXiYiZU1hHE8oKEy4aRxNDGFgBMhkGmJkADcRA2lNRlxjBAtmITrJZABeZAQYwgh0LFwCYgAKAG0TMj3qWgYAcm5Uh25uom4ifOOAGgOuswsrMls0iBOACQKoCWOyGKVCBjxBFBBh2IJzOn0utBudzBkOwUHMlmE1k83l8JwAHgABNg44SGcZ2QHAqjFAC6AEoSmUorV6mjDMhtHoDMhjldAWpNGAeaj0SJAYomJ8xhMhXBphIAExzBZLSCrbD4Wg7PYQlFHHnw4jcACCDyeItemPeXh8VuOhOJtrJygpQL2wWR%200hXX1pyuJrOLogoluMTN3otGKxNtxPIdJOdrqpbvpJTAEmwyAAaiJgDhlur1rQADwmAAqnjxkBAOGkhc1xG2NPuyBMeEr1drATcbGVIAgvWgyIA8sqy%20QAHxjjsFLvbUB5KDIAAyM5rdcwGo2RBbhj3C%20gyAASmuu-Xt02aU9kI4V9sAERXe800-SPDXqi3-uDqAf5AMHM2nzNVNyLYhiyPFt2wAHzvR9aGfFthwna8GGHEoYG0BAwGACwVQgAtQIbIhSyoCsICrWdpE2c9aGQAAyd4rgYdtgjpJsWzbV9u3YSdNm8NZiIA3NgJWIjt2LbY90MMsaQnOldSoGIwE0KAkgErdaHIYIgA)